# background-image not showing up in header

Tags: css, background-image

I want to add background-image to `<header>` tag, but the image does not show.

```
header {
    background-image: url("/img/header-bg.jpg");
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    width: 100%;
    height: 105px;
    background: #fff;
    position: relative;
    display:block
}
```

When I go to Developer Tools in Chrome, I can see that the URL to image is good (I can see the image), but what is confusing me is that when I add

```
background-image: url("/img/header-bg.jpg");
background-repeat: repeat-x;
```

as a new style rule to the `header` in Chrome, the background image shows.

Comment: Change `background` property to `background-color` or remove it. `background` is a short hand css property, It will override all other previous styles.

Comment: Swap the order of `background-image` and `background`, or instead of using `background`, use `background-color`

Comment: @MuhammadUsman Since you explained what i did wrong can you write that as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `background` property to `background-color` or remove it at all if not needed.

> `background` is a short hand css property, It will override all other previous styles.

Your code should be:

```
header {
  background-image: url("/img/header-bg.jpg");
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  height: 105px;
  position: relative;
  display:block
```

}

OR in short hand form as follows:

```
header {
  background: #fff url("/img/header-bg.jpg") repeat-x;
  width: 100%;
  height: 105px;
  position: relative;
  display:block
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Use of same background property will reflect only with color.So refer the below code:

```
header {
  background:#fff url("/img/header-bg.jpg") repeat-x;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  width: 100%;
  height: 105px;
  position: relative;
}
```

Comment: or you can use background-color

Comment: Welcome, If you feel that the answer given above is correct make a tick mark.

Comment: Since Muhammad Usman explained what i did wrong i gave him correct and i think he post it before. But yours is also correct.

Answer (score 0):

```
.heaer_area {
    background-attachment:fixed;
    background-clip: border-box;
    background-color: #000000;
    background-image: url("img/fitness.jpg");
    background-origin: padding-box;
    background-position: 0 0;
    background-repeat: repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}`enter code here`
```